# NullPointerException ao exibir Notification com PendingIntent e BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Estou consumindo uma API e chamei o BroadcastReceiver sempre que o usuário se conectar a internet. Porém, na hora de exibir o notification está aparecendo:

 "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference"

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_tem_pedido);
    builder.setContentTitle("Novo Pedido !");
    builder.setContentText("Favor, verificar o sistema !");
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    builder.setDefaults(
            NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE
    );
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https:www.google.com"));

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,
            0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_visitar_site,"Visitar site",pi);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,builder.build());
```

Nesta linha:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,
            0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Você está usando esse código aonde? Em uma classe separada ou no Main ?

Comment: O problema é que o contexto `MainActivity.this` está nulo!